# Is there a word for a positive, enriching type of escapism

Tags: single-word-requests

Escapism is a valuable tool, especially in times of extreme stress, but to me seeking escapism one is not pursuing something that will enrich or bring growth to his/her life rather simply a way to avoid dealing with unpleasant realities. To me it never rises above being a distraction.

Is there a word for getting so lost in something that for lack of a better way of saying it, feeds one's soul, i.e. great music, theater, literature, visual art, etc?

Comment: The word "Eschewal" is a synonym for escapism and has a positive connotation, but I don't think it quite captures the idea you are expressing.

Comment: I am just wondering whether a potential word that I cannot come up with would not bear a similar negative connotation. In fact, if someone is mainly focused on a matter that fascinates her/him, s/he also neglects other important matters...

Comment: [Rekall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYRVMeAwVKk)?

Comment: At its core, “escapism” defines the reason why someone does something (in order to escape reality), more so than the nature of the thing that they are doing. (I would expect that it depends heavily on the person in question what type of activity they will turn to.) Is that “in order to escape reality” bit also the central point of the new term that you seek? It sounds like it may be more about the type of activity than the reason behind it, or possibly a different reason (some form of enrichment/growth, as is mentioned), or a combination of reasons?

Comment: @Noah From dictionary.com: "verb. (tr) to keep clear of or abstain from (something disliked, injurious, etc); shun; avoid." This seems to lack the clear positive connotations that the OP requires.

Comment: Isn't this the *flow state* of total absorption, losing track of time, and oh, so happy? In positive psychology, a flow state (being in the zone) is the mental state of performing an activity immersed in energized focus, full involvement, and enjoyment in the process of the activity.

Comment: I thought flow state required a more active participation by the individual.                  Flow theory postulates three conditions that have to be met to achieve a flow state:
One must be involved in an activity with a clear set of goals and progress. 
The task at hand must have clear and immediate feedback. This helps the person negotiate any changing demands and allows them to adjust their performance to maintain the flow state.
One must have a good balance between the perceived challenges of the task at hand and their own perceived skills.

Comment: Does reading a book or listening to a concert fit the idea of an activity as defined in my previous comment?  BTW, my previous comment was from a Wikipedia page. I don't know what source would be considered definitive when defining flow state.  That being said I think getting lost in reading a book or listening to a concert seems very similar to flow.

Answer (score 2):

I submit that no such word exists.

The American writer Ursula LeGuin recently wrote this: “The direction of escape is towards freedom. So what is “escapism” an accusation of?”

It’s from her collection of essays, *No Time to Spare: Thinking About What Matters*. More here:  https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33503495-no-time-to-spare

My point is that if such a word existed, then Ms. LeGuin would have proclaimed it forcefully.

Certainly there is nothing that answers the moral accusation implicit in calling something escapist, or which has gained currency in ordinary speech.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "highbrowness" is as close a term as you may find to characterize the type of aspiration you seek to define: it does not make abstraction of "cold" intellectual aspirations  and  takes into account the humanities ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highbrow)), the arts. This is, unfortunately, a term that has come to have negative connotations, and, surprisingly, it was considered to be a colloquial term ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highbrowness&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighbrowness%3B%2Cc0)) still 25 years ago (orig. *US*). Moreover, you might more properly say of someone that he/she is given to escapism rather than given to highbrowness as this latter appears not to be someone's more or less passing way to react to reality but a more profoundly ingrained behavioural trait. It is not to be confused then with a *type* of escapism as it is a way to be and not a feature patched onto your psychological makeup, which escapist aspirations tend to be.

- On my own terms -John Seymour - 1963 -
  Any show of highbrowness would, of course, have made me quite unacceptable to any of these boys; but any highbrowness in me was latent. I certainly did not try to suppress it — I did not know it was there. I read more than the other boys, ...
- The Nineteenth Century and After - Volume 112 - 1932 - ‎Extraits - The other highbrow novelists, such as Montague, Lawrence, Forster, Huxley, owe their ' highbrowness,' not to a scorn of being easily comprehensible, but to the intellectual calibre of their work ; they are also excellent and versatile stylists.

Comment: @lhp This is a very interesting contribution, but it only seems to capture the intellectual area. How about types of passion such as gardening or similar?

Comment: @Nico Could gardening be a highbrow activity? I'd say no, not gardening  in a common sort of way, certainly not gardening aiming at a mere supply of what the distribution system can provide you with. The OP has no hobby-like activities in mind though: he is talking of "feeding" one's higher aspirations, great music, literature and the theater…

Comment: @lhp. That was exactly my point. No, gardening is not canonically a highbrow activity. I was referring to the question "Is there a word for getting so lost in something", where the nature of "something" is not specified and accordingly not restricted to "higher aspirations".

Comment: @Nico That is another question, not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @lhp The question is not about "higher aspirations" as you interpret it but about "getting so lost in something".

Comment: @Nico It must be above the level of distraction, it must be great (great music); it can't be just about anything: the theater and literature do not provide people with actual hobbies but they feed their soul with the essence of human nature and life. That is what the OP has in mind, not just anything.

Comment: Yours are philosophical considerations intertwined with personal judgments which have nothing to do with language and with the OP.

Comment: @Nico As I have been suspended from chat we won't be able to go on like that. The discussion must stop, but no, I am not all philosophical considerations and making abstraction of all linguistic notions. Read again the question, you will find in it the terms I refer to.

Comment: Yours are philosophical considerations intertwined with personal judgments which have nothing to do with language and with the OP. "Great" is not a linguistic parameter!